# Use code captcha in two forms

Tags: forms, recaptcha, code-reuse

I have two forms on a page containing Google captcha code, but only one code works. Does anyone know if you can use the same code with the same key on two forms on the same page?,
Thks,

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. But you have to explicitly render the widget as mentioned on [the developer guide](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display)

you should use something like this on your front end(taken from the developer guide):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>reCAPTCHA demo: Explicit render for multiple widgets</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var verifyCallback = function(response) {
        alert(response);
      };
      var widgetId1;
      var widgetId2;
      var onloadCallback = function() {
        // Renders the HTML element with id 'example1' as a reCAPTCHA widget.
        // The id of the reCAPTCHA widget is assigned to 'widgetId1'.
        widgetId1 = grecaptcha.render('example1', {
          'sitekey' : 'your_site_key',
          'theme' : 'light'
        });
        widgetId2 = grecaptcha.render(document.getElementById('example2'), {
          'sitekey' : 'your_site_key'
        });
        grecaptcha.render('example3', {
          'sitekey' : 'your_site_key',
          'callback' : verifyCallback,
          'theme' : 'dark'
        });
      };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- The g-recaptcha-response string displays in an alert message upon submit. -->
    <form action="javascript:alert(grecaptcha.getResponse(widgetId1));">
      <div id="example1"></div>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="getResponse">
    </form>
    <br>
    <!-- Resets reCAPTCHA widgetId2 upon submit. -->
    <form action="javascript:grecaptcha.reset(widgetId2);">
      <div id="example2"></div>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="reset">
    </form>
    <br>
    <!-- POSTs back to the page's URL upon submit with a g-recaptcha-response POST parameter. -->
    <form action="?" method="POST">
      <div id="example3"></div>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit"
        async defer>
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted a HTML snipped which I can insert multiple times, each time displaying another captcha. Also, I did not want to take care for specific IDs assigned to the containers, which would be very annoying when multiple formulars still appearing on one page will be designed and rendered independently. Here is my solution.

```js
<div class="g-recaptcha"></div>
<script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[
  function renderCaptchas() {
    var captchaNodes = document.getElementsByClassName('g-recaptcha');
    for (var i = 0; i < captchaNodes.length; i++) {
      var captchaNode = captchaNodes[i];
      if (!captchaNode.captchaRendered) {
        captchaNode.captchaRendered = true;
        grecaptcha.render(captchaNode, {"sitekey": "YOUR_SITE_KEY"});
      }
    }
  }
]]></script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=renderCaptchas&amp;render=explicit" async="async" defer="defer"></script>
```